# LINQ group by with count not returning expected results

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I am trying to create a LINQ query that will group all records in the source dataset into a single record summary line showing all objects (except for the unique identifier) and display the count of all the collapsed records. When I run a simple select query I get X records but when I run this query:

```
Dim qry2 = From j In ( _
               From Lines In DLDFDetails _
               Select Lines.Site, _
                      Lines.Service_Name, _
                      Lines.Product, _
                      Lines.PDP_Description, _
                      Lines.First_Name, _
                      Lines.Last_Name, _
                      Lines.Email, _
                      Lines.User, _
                      Lines.Change_Details, _
                      Lines.Asset_ID) _
              Group j By j.Site, _
                         j.Service_Name, _
                         j.Product, _
                         j.PDP_Description, _
                         j.First_Name, _
                         j.Last_Name, _
                         j.Email, _
                         j.User, _
                         j.Change_Details, _
                         j.Asset_ID.Count _
            Into k = Group _
            Select New With { _
                            Site, _
                            Service_Name, _
                            Product, _
                            PDP_Description, _
                            First_Name, _
                            Last_Name, _
                            Email, _
                            User, _
                            Change_Details, _
                            Count}
```

The count on the summary line shows X-Y. The unique identifier for the dataset is 'Asset_ID'. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here and what the solution is? Thanks!

Comment: What's the error? Not sure what your problem is here.

Comment: I'm not getting an error. I'm not getting the expected result. My count line is showing less than the number of records in the queried dataset.

Comment: That means that your database has rows whose site, service name, product, pdp description, first and last name, email, user, change details, and the count of their asset id are the same.

Comment: I think I'm not explaining this well. The rows for all objects except for Asset_ID will be the same, Asset_ID has a unique value for each record. When I try to get the count (I'm performing the count on the Asset_ID field) using the above query the count winds up being less than the actual number of records. I've verified that the Asset_ID values are different for each record.

Comment: Try removing the j.Asset_Id.Count and replacing it with just j.Asset_Id, and then getting the count in the select statement.

Comment: That removed the grouping completely (returned X records) all with the same incorrect count number (X-Y) I was getting before.

Comment: What is the type of `Lines.Asset_ID`? It sounds like a primitive value, so I wonder how you can `Count` it... (`j.Asset_ID.Count`). Anyway, the thing you want to count should not be part of the grouping.

Comment: It's a string. But removing it from the grouping was the solution. Thanks very much Gert!